# How to start tracking the redis operations at newrelic for python application?

Tags: python, redis, newrelic

When we start our flask application, we initialise the newrelic agent as below.

```py
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('newrelic.ini')
```

And it starts tracking the different transactions happening in the flask application. That includes, third-party external calls, MySQL/PostgreSQL/ElasticSearch operations.

Though it is not tracking the redis operations done using `rejson` package. I read somewhere that newrelic's python agent tracks the `py-redis` operations.

Are there any specific requirements/way to track redis operations in newrelic with python agent?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `rejson` has been depreciated with features merged into the `redis` library.  Have you tried changing the redis operations from `rejson` to `redis`?  I used the Getting Started example in https://pypi.org/project/redis/

Here's a Flask application I created that shows redis operations: First, I set up redis on Ubuntu.

```sh
sudo apt-get install redis
redis-server
redis-cli ping
```

Then I run my flask application

```py
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('newrelic.ini')

import redis

# Flask Web Application
flaskapp = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/")

# Navigation
@flaskapp.route("/")
def index():
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    r.set('foo', 'bar')
    return r.get('foo')

# Run Flask Web Application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    flaskapp.run()
```

Going to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ just shows `bar` as expected.

Then, in New Relic APM, I can see my `Redis set` and `Redis get` operations under Transactions, Databases, and Distributed Tracing.  As well, Redis shows up in the service map.
[image: Redis Service Map]

[image: Redis Transaction]

[image: Redis Database]

[image: Redis Distributed Tracing]

So to answer the original question, the New Relic python agent DOES track operations in the `redis-py` library.  Nothing specific was used to configure the python agent other than the application name and the license key.